# $(S_n^2-n)_{n\ge 0}$ martingale and bounded stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, stopping-times

Consider the random walk $$S_n=\sum_{k}^{n}X_{k}$$

Where $X_k$'s are iid, $$\mathbb P(X_1=1)=\mathbb P(X_1=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$$

and $\mathcal{F}_{n}=\sigma(X_i,0\leq i\leq n)$.

How do I prove that $$(S_n^{2}-n,n\geq 0)$$

is a $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-martingale, and that $\mathbb E(S_{\tau}^{2})=\mathbb E(\tau)$, where $\tau$ is a bounded stopping time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $(S_n^2-n,\mathcal{F_n})_{n\ge 0}$ *is* martingale, all you want to do is to check if you can apply [Doob's optional sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem). Basically, the theorem specifies conditions under which one is allowed to plug stopping times instead of fixed numbers into the definition of martingale. In other words, it says when
$$\mathbb{E}(X_\tau\mid\mathcal{F_\sigma})=X_\sigma$$
holds for a martingale $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\ge0}$ and stopping times s.t. $\sigma\le\tau$.

It turns out that one of the sufficient conditions is that $\tau$ is a **bounded** stopping variable, i.e. there is a constant $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\tau\le N$ almost surely. It is exactly the assumption which you have in your problem, so now you have to make a clever choice for $\sigma$ and you are done.

For a technical problem, you want to check if $$\mathbb{E}(S_{n+1}^2-(n+1)\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=S^2_n-n$$ is true. Note the $(n+1)$-th variable can be expressed in a suggestive form $$(S_n+X_{n+1})^2-(n+1)=[S_n^2-n]+[2S_nX_{n+1}]+[X_{n+1}^2-1]$$
and keep in mind the conditional expectation is a powerful thing.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $S_n^2$ can be written as $(S_{n-1} + X_n)^2$ and find the expectation of $(Sn^2 - n)$ given $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$. Here, you will need to use that the expectation of $X_n$ given previous filtrations is $0$ and its variance $1$.

Also, once you have proven that it is a martingale given to this filtration, you can use the martingale property (and the fact that $\tau$ is a finite stopping time) to equate $\mathbb E (S_{\tau}^2 - \tau) = 0$, from where you get the last equality.

Comment: Just a note: being finite and being bounded is not the same for a stopping time.