# Showing $\mathbb{E}S_{\tau}^2=\mathbb{E}\tau$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, random-walk

Suppose that $x_1, x_2,...x_n$ are independent copies of random variable $x$ having distribution $$P(x=1)=P(x=-1)=\frac{1}{2}.$$ In addition, suppose that $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{D}_{x_1,...,x_k}(k=1,...,n),$ $S_k=x_1+x_2+...+x_k$ for $(k=1,...,n)$ and $\tau$ is a stopping time with respect to the decomposition sequence $\mathcal{D}_1   \preceq  \mathcal{D}_2  \preceq  ...  \preceq \mathcal{D}_n.$ Show that $\mathbb{E}S_{\tau}^2=\mathbb{E}\tau$.

How should I start and what to use. I have no idea... I know that $\mathbb{E}S_k=\mathbb{E}x_1 \mathbb{E}k$. Do I need to show that $S_k$ is a martingale?

Comment: I just fixed it. What should I do next?

Comment: So I have no idea what I have to do. I've never had any exercise like this one.

Comment: @saz, $n$ appears to be fixed, here, so your $\tau$ is not a stopping time with respect to the filtration mentioned in the problem.  This gets around the issue you're talking about.

Comment: @MarcusM Ah, I see, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378463/s-n2-n-n-ge-0-martingale-and-bounded-stopping-times?rq=1